# UISplitView using Storyboard in Universal iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uisplitviewcontroller

I am using UISplitView in my universal iOS application and I have one storyboard only. I am able to implement all functionality except few things,

In iPad I want master view to be visible always hence I used the delegate,

```
-(BOOL)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)svc shouldHideViewController:(UIViewController *)vc inOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation
{
    return NO;
}
```

But still the master view is hiding in Portrait mode. Also in iPhone the application launches with DetailView with navigation back button. I want the iPhone application to display MasterView first. I have gone through several samples like [this](http://highoncoding.com/Articles/851_Implementing_UISplitViewController_with_Storyboards.aspx), or [this](http://nshipster.com/uisplitviewcontroller/), but nothing solved my issue.

**I am using Objective C not Swift.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at the [documentation for `UISplitViewControllerDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISplitViewControllerDelegate_protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UISplitViewControllerDelegate/splitViewController:shouldHideViewController:inOrientation:)

```
- (BOOL)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)svc shouldHideViewController:(UIViewController *)vc inOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation
```

has been deprecated in iOS8, you have to set the `preferredDisplayMode` instead:

```
controller.preferredDisplayMode = UISplitViewControllerDisplayModeAllVisible;
```

As for the iPhone app displaying the detail view controller instead of the master, implement the `UISplitViewControllerDelegate` method:

```
- (BOOL)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)splitViewController collapseSecondaryViewController:(UIViewController *)secondaryViewController ontoPrimaryViewController:(UIViewController *)primaryViewController {
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Thanks it solved master view hiding issue. However for iPhone issue it doesn't help but I have found another solution,
- (BOOL)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)splitViewController collapseSecondaryViewController:(UIViewController *)secondaryViewController ontoPrimaryViewController:(UIViewController *)primaryViewController {
    if ([secondaryViewController isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]] && [[(UINavigationController *)secondaryViewController topViewController] isKindOfClass:[CustomerDetailsViewController class]]){
        return YES;
    } else {return NO;}}

Answer (score 1):

You may set this property by user-runtime variables like this:

```
Key Path                Type      Value
preferredDisplayMode    Number      2
```

Here are the values for preferred display mode

```
case automatic = 0
case primaryHidden = 1
case allVisible = 2
case primaryOverlay = 3
```